# How to avoid bfill or ffill when calculating pct_change with NaNs

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

For a `df` like below, I use `pct_change()` to calculate the rolling percentage changes:

```
price = [np.NaN, 10, 13, np.NaN, np.NaN, 9]
df = pd. DataFrame(price, columns = ['price'])
df
Out[75]:
    price
0 NaN
1 10.0
2 13.0
3 NaN
4 NaN
5 9.0
```

But I get these unexpected results:

```
df.price.pct_change(periods = 1, fill_method='bfill')
Out[76]:
0 NaN
1 0.000000
2 0.300000
3 -0.307692
4 0.000000
5 0.000000
Name: price, dtype: float64

df.price.pct_change(periods = 1, fill_method='pad')
Out[77]:
0 NaN
1 NaN
2 0.300000
3 0.000000
4 0.000000
5 -0.307692
Name: price, dtype: float64

df.price.pct_change(periods = 1, fill_method='ffill')
Out[78]:
0 NaN
1 NaN
2 0.300000
3 0.000000
4 0.000000
5 -0.307692
Name: price, dtype: float64
```

I hope that while calculating with `NaN`s, the results will be `NaN`s instead of being filled forward or backward and then calculated.

May I ask how to achieve it? Thanks.

The expected result:

```
0 NaN
1 NaN
2 0.300000
3 NaN
4 NaN
5 NaN
Name: price, dtype: float64
```

Reference:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pct_change.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can compute the pct manually with `diff` and `shift`:

```
period = 1
pct = df.price.diff().div(df.price.shift(period))
print(pct)

# Output
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    0.3
3    NaN
4    NaN
5    NaN
Name: price, dtype: float64
```

**Update**: you can pass [`fill_method=None`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/2e218d10984e9919f0296931d92ea851c6a6faf5/pandas/core/generic.py#L11072-L11073)

```
period = 1
pct = df.price.pct_change(periods=period, fill_method=None)
print(pct)

# Output
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    0.3
3    NaN
4    NaN
5    NaN
Name: price, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks, seems we can not use `pct_change()` for this case. Since the formula of pct_change is: `(number of the current period - number of the previous period) / number of the previous period × 100%`, so I think it should be: `df.price.diff().div(df.price.shift(1))*100`?

Comment: @ahbon. My bad. I was in too much of a hurry and didn't think enough, sorry :-(. And you are right also for `pct_change`

Comment: It's okay haha. Somewhat unexpectedly, I don’t know why, the `fill_method` in `pct_change()` does not fill as one of the optional parameters. Either `bfill` or `ffill` will lead to certain errors and biases in the data.

Comment: @ahbon. I updated my answer. Can you check it :-) Totally undocumented!

Comment: Maybe a PR @Corralien?

Comment: @sammywemmy. https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/51262